# AWS CLI - S3 includes AND vs OR

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

When using the AWS CLI to interact with S3, how do I use the `--includes` filter in an AND manner? I have sample files below:

```
XYZCompany_2019-11-01_ConversionData.txt 
XYZCompany_2019-12-01_ConversionData.txt 
XYZCompany_2019-12-02_ConversionData.txt 
XYZCompany_2019-11-01_RequestData.txt 
XYZCompany_2019-12-01_RequestData.txt 
XYZCompany_2019-12-01_ConversionData.txt 
XYZCompany_2019-12-02_ConversionData.txt
```

If I use:

```
aws s3 cp s3:location local_dir --recursive --exclude "*" --include "*Conversion*"  --include "*2019-12*"
```

This treats the `--includes` in an OR manner and returns all files in December and all Conversion files. How do I retrieve only the Conversion files in December?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file names have both parts of data you are looking for, you can use 3 wildcards in a single `--includes` filter:

```
aws s3 cp s3:location local_dir --recursive --exclude "*" --include "*2019-12*Conversion*"
```

This will retrieve all Conversion files that have a date in December of 2019.